# How to install help for Office 2019 locally?

Tags: microsoft-office, help-files, microsoft-office-2019

Recently, I have installed Office 2019 Pro Plus (64 bit). Whenever I click the help button in Access, Word, Excel and so on, a browser window opens and shows a (more or less appropriate) section of Microsoft's support web sites.

Is it possible to install the help files locally?

Please note that we don't have access to volume licensing; that is an installation from the ISO file which we downloaded from Microsoft Partner Center via our MAPS subscription.

Comment: Help files are outdated, office is so complex now they do online video training now....https://support.office.com/

Comment: To expand on Moab's statment, Office 2019 to my knowlege, does not have a built-in help file.  Even the legacy "Help" file format has long been discontinued.  I am not sure your statement the ISO has anything to do with the subject, I have an ISO, and I have a Office 365 subscription.  Outside of the fact if it's Click 2 Run or MSI the Office installation is identical to one another (other then the office products that are installed).

Comment: I am mainly after the documentation of VBA, ADO and so on. I still think that a classical help file would be appropriate for that. Complexity isn't an argument against it. At least, for me: I have learned nothing from video tutorials so far, while I learned a lot from "printed" documentation. By the way, Visual Studio offered to install the documentation locally; this wasn't a help file, though. It was a browser with integrated web server and documents, but worked very well, while I often get "Unable to display help" e.g. when hitting F1 in the Access 2019 VBA Editor.